# makefile which build the library (lib.a)from the list of object files (*.o)

Tags: c++, unix, gcc, makefile, gnu

I have a problem because i have never written any makefile. So if any could help me I become happy. I have a lot of different .o files, which stored in the different folders. For example:

folder1: obj1.o
folder2: obj2.o
folder3: obj3.o

I need makefile, which will build the library from files which I send to makefile like param. Param should be makefile too and include info about folders where stored necessary files.

For example I would like to build lib from objects stored at folder1 and folder2 without folder3. So makefile which I send as param to the main makefile must include routes to folder1 and folder2:

local_libs := ../folder1
local_libs += ../folder2

main makefile should parse that info and call libtool utilite for creating lib from files at this folders. Could anybody help?

I suppose it is easy for realization, example will be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU make does not support passing parameters *"to the makefile"* on the command line.

You have two basic mechanism for setting parameters to be used by make while executing a makefile (I'm assuming that you are using GNU make, and not all of his advice will apply to other makes):

- Write to submakefiles, possibly using a script. If you makefile has a line like

  ```
  include file.mk
  ```

  gmake will include the contents of `file.mk`. Change the contents of `file.mk` and you change the behavior of your makefile.
- Make can take variable values from environment variables when set. This provides a powerful mechanism for letting the *user* customize the behavior of your makefile.

Comment: So I must include my routes into file.mk and then include it into my makefile. After doing that how can I use info stored in file.mk? Is it usual variables or no?

Comment: @user: This is an option. I am not certain exactly what you want to achieve, but these are your choices for "passing parameters" to a makefile processed by GNU make. The contents of you submakefile are make commands. You can set variables, establish dependencies, or anything else you can do in make. The submakefile becomes *part* of the file where it is included.

Comment: Could I do something like that:  
file.mk:   
local_obj := ../folder1  
local_obj += ../folder2  

then I include it into my makefile:  

include file.mk  

and here run the libtool for routes stored in local_obj?

Comment: @user: Yes. You can do anything in the included file that you could do in the body of the main makefile.

Comment: Cool, maybe you can provide example of valid rule which build the library from objects?

Comment: @user: http://dut.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dut/ is a silly little project I did a few years ago. Compare `Makefile` in the top directory with `dut_tests/dut.make`. The subfile defines variable, establishes dependencies,  and generally does a lot of work. You probably need a less sophisticated include file.

Answer (score 1):

You need a rule that inputs the `.o` files, outputs the `.a` file and calls the `ar` command to do the work.  Something like:

```
lib.a: $(OBJECTS)
    ${AR} -cr ${@} ${^}
```

Comment: And what about sending params as makefile, I am interested this more than realisation rule...